# Create list with objects from another list using RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

- I have a method: `Observable<List<String>> getNames();`
- I have object `Person` with constructors `Person()` and `Person(String name)`
- Also there is a empty list `ArrayList<Person> cachedPersons`.

What I need:
In my method using RxJava fill array with `Person` using constructor`<String>` from `List<String>` like this:

```
ArrayList<String> cachedPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();

Observable<List<String>> getNames(){
       Observable.from(getNames())
       .map{
           //cachedPersons.addAll(/*add new Person with corresponding String*/)
           //with List("John","Sara","David")
           //create cachedPersons = List(Person1("John"),Person2("Sara"),Person3("David")) 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Observable.from(getNames())
    .map{ name -> new Person(name)}
    .toList()
    .subscribe(
        list -> cachedPersons.addAll(list)
    );
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Observable.from(getNames()).subscribe(name -> cachedPersons.add(name));` ?

Comment: Not sure if i understand correctly, but i still need to return Observable<List<String>> from my function(not List<Person>), and add to cachedPersons "by the way", like inside this stream

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to fill needed **ArrayList** from **map()** method, and it is wrong.

It will never be executed until you make a **subscription**. You are not doing it in your code, so your **ArrayList** will not be filled with above code.

Do **subscription** and in **subscription** **onNext** you can fill your **ArrayList**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
Observable.from(getNames()) 
      .doOnNext(name -> cachedPersons.add(new Person(name)))
      .toList() 
      .subscribe();
```

This way you are just filling it without changing the stream value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable<SourceObjet> source = ...// get first list from here
   source.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
  .map(item -> new ResultsObject().convertFromSource(item))
  .toList()
  .subscribe(transformedList -> ...);
```

If your Observable emits a List, you can use these operators:

- `flatMapIterable` -> transform your list to an Observable of items
- `map` -> transform your item to another item
- `toList` -> transform a completed Observable to a Observable which emit a list of items from the completed Observable

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: added short description.. @yivi